# 404 errors with GD and text over image

Tags: php, image, text, gd

I am using GD to write on an image at run time. The script is working to produce the expected image and text. However, I'm getting 404 errors. The errors are only recorded in my server stats (Awstats) and in the Console of the browser I am using. No error pages are produced and the image appears normal.

I am not storing the images but am outputting them directly to the browser. To further complicate the issue, this script is the second iteration of a previous project. The earlier project has been running for over a year and does not cause any errors. The GD portion of the two scripts is the same. The only difference between the two scripts is the second, error causing, project contains more logic. Both scripts are running on the same server.

With the only error messages coming from the browser or server stats, I don't know where to look for the problem. Depending upon the browser, the error is either reported showing the whole URI necessary to produce the image or from the index.php containing the GD script. Firefox shows the old script completes the image in around 150ms. The new script times out around 1300 – 1400ms.

What can I do to learn more about what is causing the 404s?

Comment: `<?php header('Not here', 404); ?>` would cause a 404 to show up, but not be logged as a 404. if your image script is creating an image and it shows up ok, then the 404 could be a false error.

Comment: An esoteric reply? Or when is an error not an error? This is to be a commercial product. I don't think it would be right to release it with 1000's of errors a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of the 404 errors. The errors where caused by some seemingly harmless includes. when I removed them, the errors stopped.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read my question.